# get value from get_post_meta then reuse it in another get_post_meta

Tags: php, posts, post-meta, get-posts

I am writing the following code, which I have updated since the original question so as to give the entire picture. I am a newbie, and the reason why I am not using the get_posts() function in combination with an add_filter() is simply because I couldn't get it to work so I simply went back to my comfort zone and wrote a select statement. Hopefully my novice-ness doesn't get me any downvotes :-)

```
    $search_term = $request->get('search');
            
    $terms = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * 
            FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
            WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'rz_listing' 
            AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%%" . stripslashes( $wpdb->esc_like($search_term) ) . "%%'
            LIMIT $limit
        ") 
    );
    
    if( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

        if( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                        
                $rz_row = $term;
                
                // grab the icon Luke
                $placeicon = get_post_meta( $term->ID, 'rz_listing_type', true );
                $icon = get_post_meta( $placeicon, 'rz_icon', true );

            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I run the first query to get the meta_value that is used as the post_id for the subsequent query. This appears to be a very inefficient way to make two database calls, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: that is not true, when you fetch a post, all the post meta is fetched at the same time in a single database query. Your `get_post_meta` call won't hit the database unless you pass it a post ID you haven't fetched yet. Also are you sure `$term->ID` should go in there? `get_term_meta` is for term ID ( and the same applies to term meta too, WP_Cache stores it in memory until the end of the request, so if you copy paste that 100x, you don't get 100 new queries )

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I'm updating the question so you can see the whole picture. Many thanks / Luke

Comment: ah, the issue is that you used a raw SQL query to fetch your posts, that is not the optimal way to do this. You should have used `WP_Query` instead, then you would no longer have lots of small queries to the post meta table. You've also used `$wpdb->prepare` incorrectly. Also what is `rz_listing_type`? Is this a field from a field API plugin that stores a post ID? `term` has a very specific meaning in WordPress so I'd advise against using that as a variable name for non-term data, `$posts` would be a better name and less confusing

Comment: also, it only fetches the value for `rz_icon` once per post, so if you call `get_post_meta( 1, 'rz_icon', true );` 20 times then only 1 database query happens

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for your feedback Tom, I have now changed `$wpdb->prepare` in accordance with the documentation and changed $term to $post :-)